# How can I replace a value within a Sql Select which returns multiple rows?

Tags: sql

I have a table that has default values in a few columns. When I run a stored procedure to select the data for display I want to replace the default values with display friendly values.

How can I replace the default values before returning from the stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you have default values such as null, or 0?

In your sprocs, can you do a Case statement on that column?

```
CASE WHEN [Column] is Null then 'N/A'
```

Comment: Some good links on the CASE statement: 
http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/15633
http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/102704-1.shtml

Answer (score 2):

I'm at home, so I don't have examples, but you can do something like this...

```
select field1 as case
 field1 = 'val1' as 'This is the first value',
 field1 = 'val2' as 'This is the second value'
from table
```

and then the rest of the where, order or whatever else you need.  In other words, look at the case statement and the syntax for that.

Comment: Thanks! Jack was a little bit faster, but still +1 for the example.

Answer (score 1):

Couple other options for null...

ISNULL and COALESCE

Comment: ISNULL is SQL Server specific, but COALESCE is ANSI standard & supported in multiple databases.